# List of stock KitKat firmware versions for Galaxy S3 LPH-710

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, stock-android, ota-update

What stock KitKat firmware versions has Samsung released for the Galaxy S3 (Sprint model LPH-710 to be more precise)?

I got an S3 online and it came with some 4.4.x and root access. Unfortunately, when I was prompted with an OTA firmware update notification, I went ahead and installed it. I didn't back up the original firmware or check its exact version or build numbers. Due to some problems I'm now having, I'd like to get it back to its old state, as much as possible.

The strange thing seems to be that the update left me with 4.4.2 -- even though (from the googling I've done) I believe that was the first KitKat version released officially for this device. Is it possible the update either a) didn't actually update or b) was an update smaller than even a point release?

Comment: So the phone was rooted when you installed the OTA update?

Comment: Yeah. I read online that some people have success updating with it rooted, but it's uncommon; so I decided to just try it out (assuming perhaps wrongly that if it didn't like it, nothing would be modified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [site](http://www.androidayos.com/samsung-galaxy-s3-stock-firmware-2/), 4.4.2 is the only Kit Kat version for the Galaxy S3 on Sprint's network.  It is entirely possible that the update you received was just a lesser update to update some additional problems or issues that the phone might have had.

The problem is, you usually can't receive OTA updates while rooted, so there is also a chance that it tried to install, and couldn't and might have done something, but either way, what I would suggest is to flash the stock ROM, and start over from there.  Re-root if you so desire.  Might just be a bad root.

Comment: Interesting -- it specifically lists only L710VPUDND8 as baseband, but my phone shows L710VPUDNJ2. Perhaps that's a custom KitKat the previous owner put on it.

Comment: Well if it's rooted, it's likely that it's a custom ROM of kit kat.  Possibly one that was installed before the release of Kit Kat on the phone.

Comment: OK, I will definitely try the stock one with ODIN then. Should it matter if I retain CWM on it (which it didn't come with)?

Comment: @echristopherson CWM will get overwritten anyway. Odin uses the bootloader rather than the recovery to allow a full installation (including recovery).

Comment: Well, the stock firmware isn't helping so far, so I might try doing a hard reset and/or tracking down the actual L710VPUDNJ2 firmware. After setting up my accounts, it started rebooting randomly again. I also again got prompted for an OTA update, so I tried installing it (in the hopes it would help with the reboots), but once it got to recovery it gave `Error 7: /system/priv-app/GoogleServicesFramework.apk has unexpected contents`, plus some other text. I was hoping to be able to try again to capture the rest of the error, but so far haven't been able to.

Comment: http://androidbiits.com/sprint-samsung-galaxy-s3-sph-l710-android-4-4-2-kitkat-vpudnj2-l710vpudnj2/  try that link @echristopherson

Comment: I do remember another part of the error message involved an all-caps file name, something like an alphanumeric ID followed by USER_L710_ND8_TO_NJ2.zip. But I haven't seen the update notification to show up in my bar, and when I went to the update section of Settings and hit Update Firmware it gave "The firmware update could not be completed. Please try again later. [new paragraph] If the problem persists, you may need to contact Customer Service [new paragraph] Error:(Code: 407)Internal Error".

Comment: I'm now leaning toward thinking my issues with unwanted/inconsistent lock/unlock and occasional shutdowns are due to a physical problem with the power button. @New-To-IT thanks for all the help.

Comment: Correction: the file that recovery is unable to install is 0ecacf3bac0493d35771e6f691f5103b8087cf35.USER_L710 _SPR_ND8_to_NJ2_Update_FWD1.zip. And after that is "(Status 7)" (not "Error 7: " before it, as I wrote).